# What are World Object Tooltips?

Tags: starcraft-2

Within the option settings for Starcraft 2, there is an checkbox labelled "Display World Object Tooltips."

You see this setting from Menu -> Options -> Gameplay.

- What does this do?
- What classify as world objects, and which of those have tooltips?
- Under what circumstances are you able to view these tooltips?
- How do these tooltips display?

Comment: I don't have the game here, so I can't verify it right now, but I'm pretty sure those are tooltips appearing on aesthetics elements and props of the landscape, like trees or some of the indigenous creatures like the flying shark on Cloud Kingdom.  

Xel'naga, minerals and vespene gas might also be concerned by those tooltips, provinding a short description for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On standard melee maps, this option applies to:

- destructible rocks
- Xel'Naga Towers. *Tooltip: "Provides vision to nearby units".*
- neutral bunkers
- Unbuildable Plates. *Tooltip: "Unbuildable Plates".*
- Debris. *Tooltip: "Attack this to destroy it".*

But not to things like

- critters
- minerals or gas geysers

I'm concluding that the option only applies to map elements which are interactive in some form.

Comment: Just did the test: same conclusion.

Comment: minerals and gas geysers are not an important part of the game.

Comment: Ha! I really hope you were trolling just now. @Resorath

Comment: And yes, very nice question. I was wondering the same thing. The answer seems to be accurate as well.